# Array map e funções assíncronas

Tags: javascript, array, promises, next.js

Estou usando a função `getStaticProps` do Next.js e Axios para pegar notícias do site Hacker News. Meu objetivo é acessar a API que retorna as principais histórias do dia (a qual retorna um id único dessas histórias) e depois pegar os primeiros cinco ids desse retorno e fazer um novo request pelo Axios para acessar o conteúdo delas. No final passo o conteúdo como props para o componente que vai renderizar as notícias.

O problema é que para pegar as primeiras cinco eu preciso usar map para acessar os resultados de forma assíncrona. O `console.log` no código retorna vazio justamente por causa do tempo do código. Já pesquisei alguns resultados usando `Promise.all` porém nenhum que se aplique a esse caso.

Então a pergunta é: Como faço para executar o processo descrito acima usando `map` assíncrono?

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty')
  const allData = await res.data
  
  let data = []

  allData.slice(0, 5).map(async function(story) {
    
    try {
      let itemRes = await axios.get(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${story}.json?print=pretty`)
      const itemData = await itemRes.data
      
      data.push(itemData)
      
    } catch (e) {
      
      console.log(e)
      
    }
    
  })

  console.log(data)

  return {
    props: { data }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando o `map` como forma de iterar sobre cada elemento do array. Vejamos seu código:

```
allData.slice(0, 5).map(async function(story) {
  // ...
  let itemRes = await axios.get('...')
  const itemData = await itemRes.data
      
  data.push(itemData)
  // ...
})
```

Note que o *callback* que você passou ao `map` não retorna nenhum valor. Portanto, o mapeamento  está sendo feito para `undefined`.

Você deve **retornar** o valor que deseja. Se quer montar um novo *array* diretamente, utilize um `for` normal (mas nesse caso não é o que você deseja).

Uma vez que você tenha um array de promessas (criado pelo mapeamento que retorna promessas explicitamente ou tem callback sendo função assíncrona), poderá utilizar `Promise.all`. Veja:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await axios.get('...');
  const allData = res.data;

  const promises = allData.slice(0, 5).map(async function (story) {
    const itemRes = await axios.get('...');
    return itemRes.data;
  });

  try {
    const data = await Promise.all(promises);

    return {
      props: { data }
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);

    return {
      props: { data: null }
    };
  }
}
```

Note que eu fiz algumas modificações no código: adicionei ponto e vírgula e modifiquei o lugar do `try-catch` em razão do funcionamento de `Promise.all` — saiba mais [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#rejei%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Observe também que o `await` em `await res.data` não é necessário, uma vez que `data` não é uma promessa.

Para maior aprofundamento, leia:

- [Função assíncrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).
- [Objeto `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). E o método [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).
- [Método `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Obrigado pela edição e comentários. Porém quando você usou Promise.all() acho que esqueceu de adicionar promises como parâmetro. Adicionei no meu código e funcionou. Se puder verificar isso por favor.

Comment: É isso mesmo, perdão pelo erro! Já está editado. Obrigado. :) cc @Mateusqueiros